# code to find factors in PHP does not work for negative numbers

Tags: php

The code below works for factor(6) for instance. However, for factor(-8), the code return a blank page. I have tried a lot, but I cannot find out what is wrong

```
 function factor($n){
        for ($x = 1; $x <= sqrt($n); $x++)
        {
            if ($n % $x == 0)
            {
            $z = $n/$x; 
            echo "$x and $z"."<br><br>";    
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Hint :does (-8) have a square root ? If yes , what it is ? If not , try to check the for loop and tell us what values you handled. Moreover, try to add "else" after the if statement and check what happens.

Answer (score 3):

You want to avoid imaginary numbers - especially in a loop.  Seems PHP doesn't handle that very well.

Make $n positive and the function will work:

```
function factor($n){
    for ($x = 1; $x <= sqrt(abs($n)); $x++)
    {
        if ($n % $x == 0)
        {
            $z = $n/$x; 
            echo "$x and $z"."<br><br>";    
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: @user2295677 -- if this answer helped/solved it for you... Upvote it. Accept it.